# Console project fails to run in MonoDevelop 6.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I installed MonoDevelop 6.3 on Ubuntu using `flatpak install --user --from https://download.mono-project.com/repo/monodevelop.flatpakref`.

When I create a new console project and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to start it with debugging, MonoDevelop can't start it and gives me an error message saying:

> Debugger operation failed
>   Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> also doesn't work, it says:

> Cannot execute "/home/sashoalm/...

Answer (score 4):

You will need to edit the run configuration and uncheck the box that says "Run on external console," then it will run just fine.  Currently, there is no external console application inside the flatpak container, so it is not possible to run on the external console.

Comment: Worked for me with Mono 7 on Mint 18.  Thanks