# MonoDevelop on Linux: "file name has not been provided"

Tags: mono, monodevelop

I installed MonoDevelop on Ubuntu following these instructions:
http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/

I opened a new console project and ran a simple "Hello World" code.
Then, I got the following error: 
[image]

Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951799/console-project-fails-to-run-in-monodevelop-6-3-on-ubuntu No solution.

Comment: flatpack installation is experimental, please report your issue in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the 'custom configuration' from tab `run > run with > custom configuration > uncheck run on external console > run` this works for printing on console but cant insert values, `ReadLine()` does not works.