# MonoDevelop on Ubuntu using FlatPak: Debugger operation failed

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop

I installed Ubuntu MATE 17.04 in VirtualBox and installed FlatPak and MonoDevelop as described in the MonoDevelop download section.

On the download section it said: The latest stable release is 6.1 Service Release 1 (6.1.2.44).

After installation i started MonoDevelop using the flatpak command line and tried to run/debug a standard console application but it failed.

I got an error message box with the following text

```
Debugger operation failed
Cannot start process because a file name has not been provided.
```

[image: ErrorMessage]

Another issue is also that MonoDevelop shows **(as superuser)** in its titlebar.

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951799/console-project-fails-to-run-in-monodevelop-6-3-on-ubuntu duplicate and no solution.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-success-of-running-monodevelop-7-on-linux-a55f1469b1d1 Use the alternative installer and then disable external console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 7, I solved this problem by unchecking the box that said “Run on external console”. It is checked by default.  If you have difficulty finding it, look under Run -> Configurations -> Default.

[Reference](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-success-of-running-monodevelop-7-on-linux-a55f1469b1d1)

Comment: Instead of directly sharing the link. Explain it here in the answer and use link for reference purposes only.

Comment: In newer versions of the app right click your solution -> Options -> Run -> Default -> uncheck "Run on external console"

Answer (score 1):

How i found the most absurd solution to this bug!

1. Install the CodeBlocks
2. Write a Hello World in C++
3. Run the Hello World in Codeblocks
4. Then, your Monodevelop is fixed!

Original font: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoQC7HS85Xo
Teste on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

- Verify gdb is installed
- Run -> Attach to Process Debugger should be selecting GNU Debugger (GDB)
- Run -> Run custom configuration->Run Action->Debug-Mono Soft Debugger

Also, please be aware it seems that MonoDevelop settings for debugging are reset after the program has run a debugging session.

[image: GDB]