# How to debug with MonoDevelop?

Tags: debugging, mono, monodevelop

I created a regular C# console application in MonoDevelop. I can compile it (if the IDE does not crash) and I can run it in the command line. Now I'd like to debug this console program. How do I do it? MonoDevelop seems not to support that (any more?). I get the error message "Could not connect to the debugger".

Googling did not help. The only solutions suggested don't apply as they are either Unity-specific or refer to an older version of MonoDevelop. (I'm running the most recent stable mono and MonoDevelop.)

Can anyone help me please with this? Thanks!

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-success-of-running-monodevelop-7-on-linux-a55f1469b1d1 don't use external console

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Li. That worked. If the default doesn't work at all, why is this then the default??? Nevertheless it works now. Thanks!

Comment: because they expected an underlying issue to be fixed (but not yet).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console project fails to run in MonoDevelop 6.3 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951799/console-project-fails-to-run-in-monodevelop-6-3-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I'm running MonoDevelop 7.4. How old is 6.3? Your suggestion would imply: MonoDevelop is waiting for "an underlying issue to be fixed" in order to be able to debug with default settings for - at least - over 10 months now? What the hell is going on here?!?!

Comment: welcome to the open source world. If you like, you can hack it and send them pull requests at GitHub.

Comment: I know it's bad. That's why I implement a lot of open source stuff myself. If you don't do it yourself, nobody is doing it. But I didn't knew it's THAT bad.